# JSP get variable from servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have two problems,

First:

Form

```
<FORM ACTION="create" METHOD="POST">
<fieldset>
<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="paraile">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" class="button" value="Gen" />
</fieldset>
</FORM>
```

servlet method doPost

```
String ankieta = "WEB-INF/ankieta.jsp";

int ile = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("paraile"));
request.setAttribute("ile", ile);
request.getRequestDispatcher(ankieta).forward(request, response);
```

ankieta.jsp

```
  <%
  int a= Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("ile"));
      for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
  %>
         Number: <%=i%> 
  <%
      } 
  %>
```

This simple excercise doesn't work.
Really, I need loop to create a couple textbox to voting.

and my second question. When I have a few dynamic textbox, and I need their value in servlet. Can I combine them to string in jsp file and then send one parameter to servlet?

**edit:**
It's working, but still this is badly solution. Thank You Luiggi!

```
<FORM ACTION="create" METHOD="POST">
<fieldset>
<legend>Vote</legend>
<%
  String string = (String) request.getAttribute("ile");
  int a= Integer.parseInt(string);
  for (int i=1; i <= a; ++i) {
%>
    <label>Option <%=i%></label>
    <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="option<%=i%>"> 
<%
  } 
%>

<input type="submit" name="Submit" class="button" value="Accept" />
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `request.getParameter` in *ankieta.jsp* when you have set an attribute. Change it for `request.getAttribute`:

```
int a= Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("ile"));
```

Now, if you're in learning phase, I strongly recommend to **stop using scriplets**. This is heavily explained here: [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1065197)

Using EL and JSTL, the code in your JSP would be:

```html
<c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="${a}">
    Number: ${i} <br />
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: +1 for "_stop using scriptlets before you learn any more about them_".